# How to output ecx register without corrupting it?

Tags: assembly, nasm, cpu-registers

Learning how to iterate command line arguments, I want to output like this

> arg[0]: cmdl
>   arg[1]: d:/test.src
>   arg[2]: foo

Within the loop I push eax, epb and ecx, then output the arg value. Then pop the 3 registers, increment ecx, clean up stack, etc.

I have a variable reserved in .bss:

```
c:   resd    1
```

Here is my loop structure:

```
.do:
    push    ebp
    push    eax
    push    ecx

    mov     [c],    ecx

    push    DWORD   [ebx]
    push    DWORD   [c]
    push    marg
    call    _printf
    add     esp,    8       ; clean up stack

    pop     ecx
    pop     eax
    pop     ebp

    add     ebx,    4       ; move to next arg
    inc     ecx             ; increment counter

    cmp     ecx,    eax
    jne     .do
```

In the .data section, marg is defined as such:

```
marg:       db  "arg[%d]: %s", 10, 0
```

This is my current output and the app dies:

> arg[0]: cmdl
>   arg[7020225]: d:/test.src
>   arg[7019969]: foo
>   arg[7019929]: (null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not balancing the stack properly:

```
push    DWORD   [ebx]
push    DWORD   [c]
push    marg
...
add     esp,    8       <-- This is wrong
```

You've pushed 3 `DWORD`s, which is 12 bytes, but you're only "popping" 8 bytes.

So what's happening is that the string pointer that you placed on the stack with `push DWORD [ebx]` ends up in `ecx` when you do `pop ecx`. So now `ecx` is screwed, which is why you get those large argument numbers in your printouts, and why the loop never terminates.